# ipad app not works for landscape mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, landscape-portrait

iPad runs fine for portrait, but not working for Landscape,

I use this code

```
- (BOOL) isPad{ 
#ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM
    return (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
#else
    return NO;
#endif
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    if ([self isPad]) {

        return YES;
    }
    else 
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
    }

}


- (BOOL)isPadLandscape
{

    return (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad
            && (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
                || self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft));

}

- (BOOL)isPadPortrait
{

    return (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad
            && (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
                || self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown));
}




- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if ([self isPadPortrait])
    {
        [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -50, 768, 1024)];        
    }
    else if ([self isPadLandscape])
    {
        [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
    }
}
```

i try to call -(BOOL)isPadLandscape method during debug,but that method not call,

What could be wrong?

Comment: If its an iPad app then why is there "iPhone" in the title? You should make sure that what you are typing really makes sense. Always make sure you specify the tags in the tags field alone, except it is really meaningful to put it in title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to set property `Supported interface orientations (iPad)` in your Info.plist file for appropriate supported positions.

Or try this:

```
- (BOOL) isPad{ 
    return [[UIDevice currentDevice].model hasPrefix:@"iPad"];
}
```

Comment: Try to replace method `isPad` with my one.

Comment: i used your method that method call fine but  when i do a app landscape  mode at that time  - (BOOL)isPadLandscape may be call but that method not call.